# Service Layer and Simplifying Classes

Tags: c#, oop

I have a question regarding the structure of my code and how to keep classes simple. I am working on simplifying the service layer of a C# project. Much of the code has not taken into account OOP practices and there are few classes with methods over 200 lines. I have begun to extract out smaller methods but have a quick query regarding how to do this.

As an example, i have a method that retrieves file directories that are specific to a customer, then checks to see if they exist, creates them if they don't and finally returns an object with a list of these directories. I want to stick to the principle of not having private methods and extract out into new classes though traditional i would have created private methods for checking if directories exist, another for creating them, a third for retrieving the folder names and returning the object and a public method to call all of these in order with an associated interface with a single method.

Should i be creating new classes for each of these private methods and if so would they all need an interface? or perhaps keep them all public and call them from elsewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect this question will be closed. Regardless, here's how I approach it: In applications with a dedicated file storage, I tend to make a `StorageManager` class, which is responsible for serving every filepath I wish to use. It's set up in a way that any returned filepath is automatically created if it does not exist. If you have multiple storages (with different folder structures), I tend to inherit from `StorageManager` and override the path generation. Not sure if this way is objectively the best way, but I find it a clean approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you should do neither of those things.

If you want to approach the problem from an object-oriented perspective, forget for a while what the methods are doing. Think about what the code *is about*. You only mentioned "Customer" as a possible "business" relevant thing. Try to come up with other business relevant things. What are those files? Reports? ActivityLogs? Messages? CreditReports :) ?

The point is, object-orientation is not about just having methods in different classes. The classes and the methods **must** have some business meaning. If they don't mean anything, then there is no real reason to have them in the first place!

From that it is also clear that "StorageManager", "StorageUtil", and things like that shouldn't exist, because it doesn't have any business meaning at all.

So start with finding out what the application *is about* (the things), and then you can move certain responsibilities to the appropriate thing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This has made me look at the program from a different viewpoint. I can apply business logic to this as i am dealing with Order Files. So if i were to have a class that relates to processing order files, would it be better to use private methods or create new classes that concern themselves with a part of order file processing. Finally would those also require Interfaces..... i assume everything in repository and service layers should have interfaces.